# Gigabit switch on a 100 Mbps router

Tags: switch, router

I'm doing a file server setup, mainly I need Gigabit network on the line.

I've setup a Gigabit switch in which both the client machine and the server machine is connected over the same switch.

The switch is then connected to a router but just 100 Mbps, would the network between the client machine and server machine be affected and thus would be limited to 100 Mbps despite being connected to the same physical Gigabit switch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the server and the client are within the same IP network (for example they both have a 192.168.1.X address with a 255.255.255.0 (/24)) subnet mask, then they do not need a router to talk to each other and the communication will pass only through the switch, at gigabit speed.

If you use VLANs and the 2 computers are in different IP networks then they need a router to communicate and the traffic will pass through the router and will be limited to 100Mbs.